# 52 cards to be assigned randomly equally among 4 players

Tags: java, collections

I want to assign 52 cards randomly equally among 4 player. What I though that I would put each card into HashMap since the hashmap is unordered and unsorted and then iterate through it and assign the 1st 13 cards to player one and upto last 13 cards to player four. But when I iterate through hashmap the value is same all the time I want that the value should be different for each iteration. Below is the example using 6 number and output of the same.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("1", "one");
    map.put("2", "two");
    map.put("3", "three");
    map.put("4", "four");
    map.put("5", "five");
    map.put("6", "six");

    for(Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator =  map.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
        Entry<String,String> entry = iterator.next();
        System.out.print(entry.getKey()+" "+ entry.getValue() +"\n");
    }

}


Output
3 three
2 two
1 one
6 six
5 five
4 four
```

N number of times I ran the code but the output is always same in my machine. I want the different output for every run. 
Please advice.

Comment: HashMap is unordered, but that does not mean "random order". It just means "no meaningful order in particular".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple, but complete example that creates a deck of 52 integers, shuffles them, and prints one card for each player.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.shuffle;

class Deck {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> deck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // constructor
    public Deck() {
        for (int i=1; i <= 52; ++i)
            deck.add(i);
        shuffle(deck);
    }

    public void deal(int n) {
        for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
           System.out.println(deck.get(i));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Deck d = new Deck();
         d.deal(4);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the efforts. I got the point of using Collections class shuffle method for random output

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a hash map, just a plain list and `Collections.shuffle()`.

(The order of elements in a hash map is given by its hashing function, it's not random.)

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap has a consistent ordering even if it appears to be random (it's actually determined by the [hashCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) function which determines the correct "bucket") - You could try something like this instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "one");
    map.put("2", "two");
    map.put("3", "three");
    map.put("4", "four");
    map.put("5", "five");
    map.put("6", "six");

    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        keyList.add(s);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(keyList);
    for (String key : keyList) {
        String val = map.get(key);
        System.out.print(key + " " + val + "\n");
    }
}
```